# Java - Metodo Setter no actualiza el atributo de la clase luego de darle una instrucción via otro método

Tags: java, poo

***LEER EJERCICIO PRIMERO***

Bueno, acá les adjunto foto del ejercicio que tengo que hacer de la facultad:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que cuando me pide que si el numero ingresado es mayor a 100 lo settee a su máximo (100) y que cuando sea menor a 0 lo settee a su mínimo (0), el programa no actualiza los datos que esta devolviendo un método que cree para detectar si dichos números superan o no el valor dado, segun yo, no es problema de logica, debe ser mas un error de java, algo que no estoy pudiendo entender.

***Clase SuperHeroes***

```
public class Superheroes {

private String nombre;
private int fuerza, resistencia, superpoderes;

public Superheroes(String nombre, int fuerza, int resistencia, int superpoderes) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.fuerza = fuerza;
    this.resistencia = resistencia;
    this.superpoderes = superpoderes;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

private void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getFuerza() {
    return fuerza;
}

private void setFuerza(int fuerza) {
    this.fuerza = fueraDeRango(fuerza);
}

public int getResistencia() {
    return resistencia;
}

private void setResistencia(int resistencia) {
    this.resistencia = fueraDeRango(resistencia);
}

public int getSuperpoderes() {
    return superpoderes;
}

private void setSuperpoderes(int superpoderes) {
    this.superpoderes = fueraDeRango(superpoderes);

}

public static int fueraDeRango(int valor) {
    if (valor > 100) {
        valor = 100;
    }
    if (valor < 0) {
        valor = 0;
    }
    return valor;
}

public static void competir(Superheroes superheroe1, Superheroes superheroe2) {
    comparacion(superheroe1, superheroe2);
}

public static void comparacion(Superheroes superheroe1, Superheroes superheroe2) {
    int contSh1 = 0, contSh2 = 0;

    if (superheroe1.getFuerza() > superheroe2.getFuerza()) {
        contSh1++;
    } else if (superheroe1.getFuerza() < superheroe2.getFuerza()) {
        contSh2++;
    }

    if (superheroe1.getResistencia() > superheroe2.getResistencia()) {
        contSh1++;
    } else if (superheroe1.getResistencia() < superheroe2.getResistencia()) {
        contSh2++;
    }

    if (superheroe1.getSuperpoderes() > superheroe2.getSuperpoderes()) {
        contSh1++;
    } else if (superheroe1.getSuperpoderes() < superheroe2.getSuperpoderes()) {
        contSh2++;
    }

    if (contSh1 > contSh2) {
        System.out.println("TRIUNFO de " + superheroe1.getNombre());
    } else if (contSh2 > contSh1) {
        System.out.println("TRIUNFO de " + superheroe2.getNombre());
    }
    if (contSh1 == contSh2) {
        System.out.println("EMPATE!");
    }

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Superheroes [nombre: " + getNombre() + ", fuerza: " + getFuerza() + ", resistencia: " + getResistencia()
            + ", superpoderes: " + getSuperpoderes() + "]";
}
```

}

***Main***

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Superheroes s1 = new Superheroes("Batman", 101, 0, 0);
    Superheroes s2 = new Superheroes("Superman", 100, 0, 0);

    System.out.println(s1.toString());
    System.out.println(s2.toString());

    Superheroes.competir(s1, s2);

    System.out.println(s1.getFuerza());
}
```

***Output***
(En este output no estoy siguiendo el ejemplo que me da el enunciado, este ejemplo deberia retornar "EMPATE!" y el numero de abajo es simplemente la fuerza del superheroe_1, lo puse para visualmente poder saber que estaba haciendo el codigo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que corregir el constructor de este modo:

```
public Superheroes(String nombre, int fuerza, int resistencia, int superpoderes) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.setFuerza(fuerza);
    this.setResistencia(resistencia);
    this.setSuperpoderes(superpoderes);
}
```

Así, la lógica que tienes en los *setter* se usará también para establecer los valores cuando los pasas en el constructor.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! <3